# Container-Optimized OS k8s nodes losing google-ip-forwarding-daemon.service IPs

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-container-os

**Versions:** Kubernetes `v1.9.2` running in GCE (kube-up.sh)

Container-Optimized OS `10032.88.0`

---

**Symptom:** Our COS nodes show the following in their `google-ip-forwarding-daemon.service` logs:

```
Mar 07 13:43:28 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[935]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.28.188', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.120.8', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.28.188', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.120.8', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] by adding None and removing [u'104.154.243.135'].
Mar 07 13:43:45 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[935]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.28.188', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.120.8', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.120.8', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] by adding None and removing [u'104.198.28.188'].
Mar 07 13:44:01 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[935]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.120.8', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.120.8', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] by adding None and removing [u'104.197.171.xxx'].
Mar 07 13:44:17 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[935]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.120.8', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] by adding None and removing [u'130.211.120.8'].
Mar 07 13:44:37 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[935]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] by adding None and removing [u'104.198.52.xxx'].
Mar 07 13:44:53 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[935]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] by adding None and removing [u'104.197.17.xx'].
Mar 07 13:45:10 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[935]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] by adding None and removing [u'104.155.181.xx'].
Mar 07 13:45:26 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[935]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] by adding None and removing [u'104.197.255.xxx'].
Mar 07 13:45:43 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[935]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] by adding None and removing [u'104.197.166.xxx'].
Mar 07 13:45:59 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[935]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] by adding None and removing [u'146.148.61.xx'].
Mar 07 13:46:19 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[935]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] by adding None and removing [u'104.197.104.xxx'].
Mar 07 13:46:41 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[935]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] by adding None and removing [u'104.198.172.xxx'].
Mar 07 13:46:58 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[935]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] by adding None and removing [u'104.198.162.xxx'].
Mar 07 13:47:14 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[935]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] by adding None and removing [u'104.155.131.xxx'].
Mar 07 13:47:34 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[935]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] by adding None and removing [u'104.198.131.xxx'].
Mar 07 13:47:53 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[935]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] by adding None and removing [u'104.154.72.xxx'].
Mar 07 13:48:10 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[935]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] to [u'130.211.238.xxx'] by adding None and removing [u'104.154.20.xx'].
Mar 07 13:48:26 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[935]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'130.211.238.xxx'] to None by adding None and removing [u'130.211.238.xxx'].
```

When this happens, running PODs typically continue running yet sometimes become Unknown and are rescheduled. Any newly scheduled pods are stuck in ContainerCreating with these errors:

`Failed create pod sandbox.` & `Error response from daemon: network none not found`

We haven't found a fix to this symptom other than rebooting the instance.

Comment: Can you post full command for create cluster what you used

Comment: This cluster was created using kube-up.sh (https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/gce/) to create a kubernetes 1.2 cluster and was upgraded to kubernetes 1.9.2 using upgrade.sh (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/gce/upgrade.sh) to upgrade between major versions.

If you have any questions regarding my kube-env or specific kube-apiserver/kubelet args I am also happy to provide those, too.

Comment: Problem on your network driver. Try to remove /etc/cni/net.d and restart kubelet or try to set another driver `kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"`

Comment: Is docker's live-restore enabled on your node? If so, trying disabling it and restart the docker daemon when you run into the same issue again to see if the node can recover from that.

Comment: @Yu-JuHong holy moly, that worked! Do you know anything about the effects of disabling live-restore on our k8s nodes? Will we lose some stability by doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mar 12 13:21:04 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[955]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from None to [u'104.155.131.xxx'] by adding [u'104.155.131.xxx'] and removing None.
Mar 12 13:21:21 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[955]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.155.131.xxx'] to [u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx'] by adding [u'104.154.72.xxx'] and removing None.
Mar 12 13:21:37 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[955]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx'] to [u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx'] by adding [u'104.198.131.xxx'] and removing None.
Mar 12 13:21:53 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[955]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx'] by adding [u'104.154.20.xx'] and removing None.
Mar 12 13:22:10 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[955]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] by adding [u'130.211.238.xxx'] and removing None.
Mar 12 13:22:26 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[955]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] by adding [u'104.154.243.xxx'] and removing None.
Mar 12 13:22:43 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[955]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] by adding [u'104.198.52.xxx'] and removing None.
Mar 12 13:22:59 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[955]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] by adding [u'104.198.28.xxx'] and removing None.
Mar 12 13:23:15 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[955]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] by adding [u'104.197.171.xxx'] and removing None.
Mar 12 13:23:28 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[955]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.238.xxx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.120.x', u'130.211.238.xxx'] by adding [u'130.211.120.x'] and removing None.
Mar 12 13:23:42 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[955]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.120.x', u'130.211.238.xxx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.120.x', u'130.211.238.xxx'] by adding [u'104.197.255.xxx'] and removing None.
Mar 12 13:23:58 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[955]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.120.x', u'130.211.238.xxx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.120.x', u'130.211.238.xxx'] by adding [u'104.197.17.xx'] and removing None.
Mar 12 13:24:15 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[955]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.120.x', u'130.211.238.xxx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.120.x', u'130.211.238.xxx'] by adding [u'104.155.181.xx'] and removing None.
Mar 12 13:24:31 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[955]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.120.x', u'130.211.238.xxx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.120.x', u'130.211.238.xxx'] by adding [u'104.197.166.xxx'] and removing None.
Mar 12 13:24:48 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[955]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.120.x', u'130.211.238.xxx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.120.x', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] by adding [u'146.148.61.xx'] and removing None.
Mar 12 13:25:01 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[955]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.120.x', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.120.x', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] by adding [u'104.197.104.xxx'] and removing None.
Mar 12 13:25:17 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[955]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'130.211.120.x', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.120.x', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] by adding [u'104.198.172.xxx'] and removing None.
Mar 12 13:25:34 kube-minion-0fqw google-ip-forwarding[955]: INFO Changing eth0 IPs from [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.120.x', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] to [u'104.154.20.xx', u'104.154.72.xxx', u'104.154.243.xxx', u'104.155.131.xxx', u'104.155.181.xx', u'104.197.17.xx', u'104.197.104.xxx', u'104.197.166.xxx', u'104.197.171.xxx', u'104.197.255.xxx', u'104.198.28.xxx', u'104.198.52.xxx', u'104.198.131.xxx', u'104.198.162.xxx', u'104.198.172.xxx', u'130.211.120.x', u'130.211.238.xxx', u'146.148.61.xx'] by adding [u'104.198.162.xxx'] and removing None.
```

In this question's comments, [Yu-Ju Hong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5265822/yu-ju-hong) suggested disabling docker [live-restore](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/live-restore/). This insightful suggestion works to alleviate the symptom. Having read the live-restore docs, can anyone confirm if one of the benefits gained from enabling docker's live-restore (within the kubernetes ecosystem) is preserving Running pods between instance restarts? If so, is this protection-between-restarts-behavior the primary benefit to enabling live-restore in kube? We're running a few nodes with live-restore disabled as a test, however I'm trying to discover the full impact of disabling this feature.

Comment: Yes, live-restore allows containers to continue running even if the docker daemon restarts.

Comment: If you want live-restore enabled, you can wait and upgrade to 1.10, or pick up this patch to fix the configuration: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/54805

Answer (score 1):

There are too many versions between Kubernetes 1.2 and 1.9.2, why are you trying to create a very old version and then upgrade it? I followed the same Kubernetes doc and got a cluster running 1.9.3 without issues. You should try the same and verify if the issue you described persist.

Additionally, the image [cos-stable-63-10032-88-0](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/release-notes#cos-stable-63-10032-88-0) is not the latest release. You should also try running with [cos-stable-64-10176-62-0](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/release-notes#cos-stable-64-10176-62-0) instead.

Comment: Absolutely, I hear your point. In fact, I notice many differences between kube-up.sh-style 1.9.2 clusters and my upgrade.sh-upgraded 1.2->1.9.2 cluster. It has been upgraded in this manner because it is a production cluster with significant traffic/workload.